# running apache web server on an arbitrary port?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, firewall, internet

Because the ISP blocks port 80 this prevents my running a web server.  As a work-around it's possible to specify a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30703899/262852) port for Apache?  I believe I've seen mention of using port 81, or some [lower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152081/17056) ports.

Not for production, just [mucking](https://forums.docker.com/t/multiple-domains-on-shared-machine/43435) around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a recent version of Linux and Apache.

To accomplish this configuration change, modify

```
 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

replacing the

```
Listen 80
```

directive with a different port.

As far as ports go, I'd recommend higher.  Check a [list of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), go high and stay away from known ports.